# Understanding Android Multiple Device Layouts

Tags: android

Ok, I have read all of the other posts regarding multiple device layouts and the android docs, yet I still managed to stuff it up!

I made the mistake of testing this application using my HTC Sensation HD. So when I decided to emulate it on the HTC Desire (medium screen res) imagine my shock that it wasn't even close to fitting.

I used DIP for EVERYTHING. So why on earth does half the screen fall off when using the emulator in the Desire medium resolution. I thought it would just scale down. if not, what am I supposed to do?

I have attached a Picture of the result. A dropbox download of a Working project (a dumbed down version) and the xml attached here. As you see, four controls have dropped off the page.

I need this App to work on large, medium and Small devices. (Sensation HD, Desire, Cha Cha). Any advise would be awesome.

[PROJECT LINK](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55825865/AndroidCrossDevice.zip)

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:paddingRight="20dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/clientLogo_TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dip"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:src="@drawable/logotop" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOne_Button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:text="Button One" >
</Button>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/customshape"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="7dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelOne_TextView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Label One"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelTwo_TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Label Two"
            android:textSize="13dip" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTwo_Button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Button Two"
            android:textSize="16dip" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sliderLabel_TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="Slider"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sliderStatus_TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" - Status"
            android:textSize="13dip" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sliderOne_SeekView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="10" >
    </SeekBar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelThree_TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Label Three"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerOne_Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerTwo_Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelFour_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Label Four"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerThree_Spinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dip"
                android:layout_weight=".4" >
            </Spinner>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelFire_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Label Five"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerFour_Spinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dip"
                android:layout_weight=".4" >
            </Spinner>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ButtonsLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonThree_Button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button Three" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFour_Button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button Four" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Side note, use sp instead of dp/dip for font sizes.

Answer (score 3):

Device-independent pixels (dip) are intended to make your pixel measurements uniform across different screen **densities**.  Screen size and density are two different things.  You still need to code your layouts to span physical screen sizes.

For example, nearly all 10-inch tablets right now have a medium-density screen, despite the fact they have an "extra-large" screen size.  That's because even though the screen is physically large, it doesn't pack in the pixels as densely as on some high-end phones, such as the Galaxy Nexus.

In order for your layouts to adapt to different screen sizes, you need to account for this in the structure of your layout.  This means several things:

- Avoid hard-coded dimensions whenever possible.  If you can, use `match_parent` to allow a UI widget to encompass available space.
- Try not to stack so
  many controls so they go off the screen of the smallest device you'll
  be using, or put the controls into a `ScrollView`.
- Center controls in
  available screen space.  You can group a set of controls with a
  layout container such as `LinearLayout`, then center that within
  another layout manager with `android:layout_gravity`.  You can also
  use `android:gravity` on some widgets (notably `TextView` and `ImageView`)
  to center their content within the bounds of the view itself.
- Android will allow you to create custom layouts for each combination of screen size and density, if you need to custom-tailor a layout for a particular class of device, such as a 7-inch tablet or a 3-inch phone.  See the [Android SDK docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).
- To span a very wide range of screens, you can take advantage of the
  Fragments API to stack related layouts on a tablet-sized screen, but
  show them individually on a phone screen.

There's other techniques, but the key thing to note is that using dip doesn't automatically scale your layout to encompass all screen sizes.  You have to address the matrix of screen size and density.

Comment: +1 - This is a great answer. If only I had known this to begin with. So is it best to get the layout working for a medium density phone like the Desire first. Avoid any height specifications. The use a scroll view for the smaller phones, and write a new layout completely for the larger and higher density phones? I need to cover a popular range of phones. However, the client wants the layout above, so i dont have the option to simplify what is there. Any additional advice on how to approach the design process would be great.